# Flutter - A RenderFlex overflowed by 81 pixels on the bottom

Tags: android, flutter, dart

good afternoon, I'm new in android programming. And I want to ask about the error in my code. the error is "The following assertion was thrown during layout:
A RenderFlex overflowed by 81 pixels on the bottom." . I've tried to find a solution but still nothing works. and this is my code. thank you

```
class berita_secondpage extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title;

  berita_secondpage({
    this.title,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(title),
        ),
        body: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              child: Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                          bottomLeft: Radius.circular(30),
                          bottomRight: Radius.circular(30)),
                      image: DecorationImage(
                        image: AssetImage("assets/images/aquaman.jpg"),
                        fit: BoxFit.cover,
                      ))),
            ),
            Container(
              height: 260,
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 20, 20, 0),
                    child: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text(
                          title,
                          style: TextStyle(
                            // color: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
                            fontSize: 25,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                          ),
                        ),
                        Text(
                          "diupload pada : 20 Agustus 2021",
                          style: TextStyle(
                            // color: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
                            fontSize: 10,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          width: 15,
                        ),
                        Text(
                          "testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing",
                          style: TextStyle(
                            // color: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
                            fontSize: 17,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            )
          ],
        ));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Your problem is the occur because of your 2nd container height. you give container height 260, but your text need more space for display.
> **Remember, 'A RenderFlex overflowed ...... ' want to tell you that your data (image/text) need more space, but you give him little space.**

```
class SecondPage extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title;
  SecondPage({required this.title});

     @override
     Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return Scaffold(
         appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text(title),
    ),
    body: Container(
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: Container(
              decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.red,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                    bottomLeft: Radius.circular(30),
                    bottomRight: Radius.circular(30)),
                image: DecorationImage(
                  image: NetworkImage('https://picsum.photos/250?image=9'),
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            height: 360,
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 20, 20, 0),
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text(
                        title,
                        style: const TextStyle(
                          // color: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
                          fontSize: 25,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                        ),
                      ),
                      const Text(
                        "diupload pada : 20 Agustus 2021",
                        style:  TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
                          fontSize: 10,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                        ),
                      ),
                      const   SizedBox(
                        width: 15,
                      ),
                      const Text(
                        "testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing",
                        style:  TextStyle(
                          // color: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
                          fontSize: 17,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    ));
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding your second `Container` to a `Flexible` widget. The error simply says that the widget is larger than the viewport.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your Column in Wrap component

```
Container(
              height: 260,
              child: Wrap(
                children: [
                  Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 20, 20, 0),
                        child: Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Text(
                              title,
                              style: TextStyle(
                                // color: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
                                fontSize: 25,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                              ),
                            ),
                            Text(
                              "diupload pada : 20 Agustus 2021",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                // color: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
                                fontSize: 10,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                              ),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(
                              width: 15,
                            ),
                            Text(
                              "testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                // color: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
                                fontSize: 17,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            )
```

Comment: this is not error. but my text is cut off (it doesn't scroll until the end of my text)

Comment: ```Container(
              height: 260,
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Column(...),
              ),
            )```

Answer (score 0):

```
Container(
              height: 260,
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 20, 20, 0),
                      child: Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Text(
                            title,
                            style: TextStyle(
                              // color: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
                              fontSize: 25,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                            ),
                          ),
                          Text(
                            "diupload pada : 20 Agustus 2021",
                            style: TextStyle(
                              // color: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
                              fontSize: 10,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                            ),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            width: 15,
                          ),
                          Text(
                            "testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing",
                            style: TextStyle(
                              // color: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
                              fontSize: 17,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            )
```